# Solve Proof by Induction with 2 variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am not sure how to solve a proof by induction using $2$ variables. Do I solve for $n$ first and then $q$, or vice versa? Can you please give me a hint? Thanks.

> Prove by induction on $n$ that for any real number $q>1$ and integer $n\ge 0$: $$1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-1}+q^n=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}\;.$$

Comment: The problem tells you that the induction is to be on $n$; $q$ is simply an unspecified constant independent of $n$.

Comment: It's says prove by induction on $n$. I believe the condition $q > 1$ is to say that the sum of the $q$ terms is to be positive and that $q - 1 \neq 0$.

Comment: ok. For n =0, what is term on the left hand side? It cannot be 1...

Comment: Why not? If $n = 0$ then 1 = $\frac{q-1}{q-1}$ which holds..

Comment: @Ed_4434 When n = 0, the left side will be q^-1 + q^0. This is not equal to zero. I am probably making a mistake here though...

Comment: @Avi $n \geq 0$, if $n = 0$ then the expression on the LHS is just 1. If I write it as a sigma summation, you have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k$$

and if $n = 0$, this is simply $1$.

Comment: @Ed_4434 Ok. So we do not use the term q^(n-1)? If so, can you please say why? Thanks

Comment: I will finish this in an answer.

Comment: ok. thank you very much.

Comment: You do not use the term $q^{n-1}$ when $n=0$ for the same reason you do not use the terms $q^1$ or $q^2$ when $n = 0$. The notation of the sum on the left is meant to show you what the first term of the sum must be (if it exists), what the last term must be (if it exists), and to show the pattern that gives the terms between the first and last (if they exist). Notice where I wrote _if_. Sometimes the first and last terms will be equal and there will be no terms between them. If $n=-1$ then even the first and last terms would not exist, which is why the problem statement requires $n\geq0$.

Comment: Note that some day you may encounter a proof that really does require induction over two variables. Most likely both those variables will be required to be integers; certainly neither of them will be allowed to be anything like "any real number $q > 1$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove by induction on $n$, the "standard procedure" is to prove for a base case, assume for $n = k$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$ and then to show that the argument also holds for $n = k+1$.

**Base Case**:
Since we are given that $n \geq 0$, our lowest possible value for $n$ is $0$, so let $n=0$. Then,

$$1 = \frac{q-1}{q-1}$$

which is true, so the statement is true for $n = 0$. Your confusion here is that if $n=0$, the summation is simply

$$\sum_{k=0}^0 q^k = q^0 = 1.$$

**Induction hypothesis:**

Since we have shown that the statement holds for at least one $n\geq0$, let's assume that it holds for some $k\in \Bbb N$. Then

$$1 + q + q^2 + \cdots + q^{k-1} + q^k = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q -1}.$$

**Proof for $n = k+1$**:

Now let's show that the statement holds for $n = k+1;$

If we let $n = k+1$ then we have that

\begin{align}
1 + q + q^2 + \cdots + q^k + q^{k+1} &= \frac{q^{(k+1) +1} -1}{q-1}\\
&=\frac{q^{k+2} -1}{q-1}.
\end{align}

Notice that, up until the $q^{k+1}$ term, we actually have what we had in our inductive hypothesis. So we can write

$$\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q -1} + q^{k+1} = \frac{q^{k+2} -1}{q-1}.$$

Placing the LHS over a common denominator, we have that

\begin{align}
\frac{q^{k+1} - 1 + q^{k+1}(q-1)}{q -1} &= \frac{q^{k+1} - 1 + q^{k+2}-q^{k+1}}{q -1}\\
&=\frac{q^{k+2} -1}{q-1},
\end{align}

as desired.